# perform shell variable substitution when using find file at point (ffap)

Tags: shell-mode, ffap

> **Question:** is there a way to convince `ffap` to perform variable substitution on environment variables before attempting to resolve the file path?

---

I often have lines in shell scripts that read:

```
variable="${ENV_VAR}/path/to/file"
```

When I use `ffap` on the above, it is unaware of what `${ENV_VAR}` means. Assume `ENV_VAR` is properly defined via

```
export ENV_VAR="/path/to/dir"
```

in one of the shell's init-files and it can be found in the output of `env`. Is there a way we can trick `ffap` to do the variable substitution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can redefine `ffap-file-finder`. This is normally set to `find-file`, which doesn't do env variable expansion. So define a function like `find-file` that *does* do env variable expansion:

```el
(defun find-file-env (fname)
   (find-file (substitute-in-file-name fname)))
```

and assign it to `ffap-file-finder`:

```
(setq ffap-file-finder #'find-file-env)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've done the above, and it works "partially". When having a string like `"${INCL_PATH}/path/to/foo"`, it will now recognize `${INCL_PATH}` and it will recognize `/path/to/foo` (depending on the location of the cursor), but it will not recognize both combined. It does work when removing the braces.

Comment: This might be related to [this bug](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gnu-emacs/2015-04/msg00133.html)

Comment: Looks like it is, yes.